# One liner result of Async in JS?

Tags: javascript, object, import, async-await, iife

I would like to assign the result of an async IIFE function to an object property.

Something like:

```
const myObj = {
    dep: (async () => { await import('./myDep'); return myDep;})(),
}
```

But instead of getting the value I get the promise.

Currently I have to use this which is ugly:

```
let myObj = {};

(async () => {
    await import('./myDep');
    return myDep;
    })().then((myDep) => {                                                            
        myObj = {
            dep: myDep
        }
    }
});
```

---

With top level async, which still is in ECMAScript proposal state I believe this would be simply:

```
const myObj = {
    dep: await import('./myDep'),
}
```

Comment: Put your script into an `async` function, then use your last method

Comment: `import("./myDep").then(() => myObj.dep = myDep);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JonasWilms

In the end I did this:

```
const myObj = {};

import("./myDep").then(m => myObj.myattrib = m.namedexport);
```

This works as expected and I have the `myObj` with the `myattrib` attribute as the named export of `myDep`.